# Modifying center of equirectangular world map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj

I'm trying to make a custom CRS in QGIS, to get a projection similar to this map, where Toronto is at the center of the map :

[image]

The picture above was created with an online tool : [worldmapcreator](http://worldmapcreator.com/#!/home)

But I can't get enough details with this tool, that's why I need a way to project a similar map in QGIS.

I tried to create a custom CRS, but I'm not a geographer...
I'm not familiar with *proj4* language and I struggle a lot.
I only managed to change the central longitude on a WGS 84 projection, but I can't move the equator.
The only time I was able to put Toronto at the center was in a circular map, but I need an rectangular map...

So, what parameters should I use to get a projection featuring :

- the whole world in a equirectangular map
- Toronto at the very center of the map

I don't care about the distortions at the top and bottom of the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A helpful page for customizing projections in QGIS is [this one,](http://proj4.org/parameters.html) explaining the parameters of Proj.4 projections.

To get you started I would sugget the Michigan oblique Mercator projection; it should get you pretty close to what your after, which makes it a good starting place parameter-wise.

```
+proj=omerc +lat_0=45.30916666666666 +lonc=-86 +alpha=337.25556 +k=0.9996 +x_0=2546731.496 +y_0=-4354009.816 +no_uoff +gamma=337.25556 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

Another option is the Miller projection [+proj=mill] or the Equidistant Cylindrical (Plate Carrée) [+proj=eqc] if you're wanting to keep the rectangular shape. (I have not experimented with rotating the perspective - lambda, phi, gamma - on these projections though)

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: Oblique Mercator seems to be the only rectangular projection that allows rotation, thank you for the formula. I managed to put Toronto at the center. The only downside is that mercator projection crops a little part of the map, so I can't get 100% of the surface of the world.

I tryed Miller and Plate Carrée, but rotation didn't work.

So, I guess this is as close as I can get, using QGIS.

Comment: updated link: https://proj.org/usage/projections.html

Answer (score 1):

Upon some further research, I came across ["Adaptive Composite Map Projections"](https://ir.library.oregonstate.edu/downloads/nv9357974) by Bernard Jenny. In it I found this graphic of interest. Maybe the Hammer or Modified Hammer projection is the way to go.

I also came across [Flex Projector,](http://www.flexprojector.com/download.html) a custom projection software Jenny has developed. I haven't downloaded it myself, but it might be worth a shot; looks like it could be exactly what you're after.

[image: B.Jenny]

Comment: Very interesting! I will give it a try, thank you.